# References in element variable of for loop

Tags: rust

I'm having difficulty understanding why this snippet from [The Rust Book, Chapter 10](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html) works:

```rust
fn largest(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut max = arr[0];
    for &i in arr.iter() {
        if i > max {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    max
}
```

**Assumption A:** Using `arr.iter()` will return references to the items in the array/slice/vector when iterating over it. So `i` will be of type `&i32`. Adding the extra `&` in the definition will make it a reference to a reference, so `&&i32`.

**Assumption B:** The [IndexMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) trait (used in line 2) will return a mutable reference to the item at index, so in this case a `&mut i32`.

Both of these assumptions are wrong, given that both `i` and `max` are of type `i32`. Why?

---

Additionally, I understand that `i32` implements the `Copy`-trait, but since I'm not moving ownership anywhere in this code (because everything is a reference) it shouldn't be used here, right?

---

Lastly, if I leave the `.iter()`-call out, it works aswell. I assume that the compiler infers from the `&i`-definition, that the `iter()` should be used (and not `iter_mut()` or `into_iter()`), correct?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with Copy shouldn't be used. It's used when you return the value for example.

Comment: @DenysSéguret ignoring the final return for now, is it used anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

In

```
for &i in arr.iter() {
```

you're not *adding* a `&`: this is [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html). You're matching `&i` to the results of the iteration, thus *removing* the `&`.

It's effectively just like doing

```
for i in arr.iter() {
    let i = *i;
```

Comment: Can you expand on Assumption B ?

Comment: `max` is of type `i32`, not `&i32`

Comment: Yeah, but why? As mentioned, the IndexMut trait should be used which says it will return `&mut i32`. Why is it `i32`?

Comment: IndexMut would be used if the indexing was left side of the assignment, not right side, or with max = &mut arr[0]. And it would also need the array to be mutable. The trait used here is Index

Comment: Thats interesting, i didn't realize the side of assignment was relevant! But wouldn't that mean that `arr[0]` returns a `&i32` (as the Index-trait defines)?

Comment: Read [there](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ops/trait.Index.html): *"container[index] is actually syntactic sugar for *container.index(index)"* (the important detail is the `*`). As for the IndexMut it's not precisely the side of the assignment  which matters but whether the context of the expression needs to be mutable (when it's left side of an assignment it always is). If you were to declare `let max: &i32 = &mut arr[0]` then you'd asking for a mutable context.